# trouble with if else statement... important

Tags: java, if-statement

sorry my tittle is a little broad. but im taking computers in grade 12 and my assignment is to make a little program that generates numbers and if it is equal to another set of numbers, you win, kind of like a lottery. i found it difficult to make the random number generator work twice so i pre loaded one of the number variables. now my last task is to get it to say "you win" if one of the numbers match, and if not "you loose", basically i just cant match the variables?`

```
Random rn = new Random();

String answer = " 3\n 12 \n 27";
for(int i =0; i < 3; i++)
{
    int answer1 = rn.nextInt(30) + 1;

   delay(2000);
    System.out.println(answer1);

}
    System.out.println("And the winning numbers are...");

delay(2000);
    System.out.println(answer); }


    `
```

ive gotten a little bit further but my 'win' wont seem to be resolved to a variable, here is my new code`

```
 Random rn = new Random();

String answer = " 3\n 12 \n 27";
for(int i =0; i < 3; i++)
{
    int answer1 = rn.nextInt(30) + 1;


    System.out.println(answer1);


    System.out.println("And the winning numbers are...");


    System.out.println(answer); 

     if (answer1 == 3)
     if (answer1 == 12)
     if (answer1 == 27)
         win = true;

 if (win) {
System.out.println("You win!");
 } else
System.out.println("You loose");
}`
```

Comment: I don't see any if statement?

Comment: Stackoverflow might be not the best place for asking homework..

Comment: because i dont know how to make one in this situation, the int answer1 is in a body so it wont let me use it outside of the body?

Comment: create an array outside of that loop and upon successful match insert numbers into it. So at the end if array length is greater than one you win

Comment: Put the declaration of answer1 one outside the body of your for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code's problem is that you will win a successful lottery only after long time. Try to make some algo for it to increase the probability for winning.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Lottery{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Random rn = new Random();

        int ch = 1;
        while(ch == 1){
            String str = "";
            String str1 = "";
            String str2 = "";

            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                int answer1 = rn.nextInt(9) + 1;

                //delay(2000);
                str = str + "-" + answer1;
                str1=str1+answer1;
            }

            System.out.println(str);
            str = "";

            for(int i =0; i < 3; i++){
                int answer1 = rn.nextInt(9) + 1;

                //delay(2000);
                str = str + "-" + answer1;
                str2 = str2 + answer1;
            }
            System.out.println(str);

            if(Integer.parseInt(str1) == Integer.parseInt(str2)){
                System.out.println("Crongrats !! You are the Lucky Winner !!!!");
            }   
            else
                System.out.println("Better Luck Next Time");

            System.out.println("Wanna Try Again ? 1=YES, 0=NO");
            ch = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        }
        System.out.println("Thanks for Playing Lottery with us !! Come back soon");
    }
}
```

Comment: i was just wondering, could you help me make it so i could just get one of the numbers right i would "win"?

Answer (score 0):

> now my last task is to get it to say "you win" if one of the numbers match, and if not "you loose"

Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Random rn = new Random();
        int preloadedAnswer = 19;
        boolean win = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            int answer1 = rn.nextInt(30) + 1;
            if (answer1 == preloadedAnswer)
                win = true;
        }
        if (win) {
            System.out.println("You win!");
        } else
            System.out.println("You loose");
    }
```